# Angular 9 unable to get route param inside sub module

Tags: angular, routes, git-submodules, angular9, routeparams

I'm facing a problem while trying to get route params inside a sub module.

We are having two module **Project** and **Ticket**. **Project** is the main module and **Ticket** is the sub module.

The route which I try to create is like. "project/:id/ticket/" --> "/project/1/ticket/".

**project-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children:[
      {
       path: 'ticket',
       loadChildren: () => import('../ticket/ticket.module').then(m => m.TicketModule),
      }  
   ]
  }]
```

Inside that **Ticket** module. I have component called view. where I need the project id which is in the route url "/project/1/ticket". I tried the following code to get the route param. But I only get the value **undefined**.

**ticket-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [ {
  path: '',
  component: ViewComponent
}]
```

**view.component.ts**

```
  this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {  // Here params giving -> {}
    this.projectId = +params["id"];
  });
```

I'm unable to get the route params inside this sub module.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access `parent` of the `route`. 
Try to do

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.projectId = +params.get('id');
});
```

Comment: I tried both ways. But still, receiving the empty object in params. But when I try to get the route params inside the sub module. I can able to get the route params.